# Inline If-Statement Java

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-operator

all! I have been learning how to use ternary statements in Java, and I reached this stage:

*variable* = (*condition*)? *what happens if condition is false* : *what happens if condition is true*

Although, I have been wondering if that can be applied if I don't want the code to do anything when the condition is false. I know that you can just do:

if (*condition*) {*action*}

So is it possible to use the ternary statements without assigning the false conditions, and if so how?

Thank you!

Comment: Note it's the other way around: `condition ? <if-true> : <if-false>`.

Comment: You cannot do _nothing_ on the else-case, you have to do some kind of no-op, for example `int i = 5; i = (condition) ? 6 : i;`

Comment: Typically a ternary is used to determine a _value_ rather than to necessarily invoke code. In that sense, doing a ternary by itself on a line isn't even valid. If you hit a `false` condition, what should happen in your fantasy-ternary? Your `if` example wouldn't do value-assignments short of `if (cond) variable = value;`, but that's usually poorly-formed.

Comment: you should better replace "*what happens*" by "*what results*" - the second and the third *terms* are expressions, not statements - there must be some values both results in

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'ternary statement' - the **conditional operator** (which is its [real name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)) is an **operator** in an **expression**.    In this case, the common-but-wrong name, "ternary operator", actually answers the question.  "Ternary operator" just means "operator with 3 operands".  So, no - an operator with 3 operands can't have 2 operands.

Answer (score 5):

The conditional `?:` operator is *not* an inline `if` statement.

`?:` is not a statement. It's an expression. You can only use it in a way that always yields a value. In other words, you *have to* provide a value for when the condition is both true and false.

Just live with the "verbosity" of an `if` statement.

---

A few demonstrations of why `?:` isn't an inline `if` statement:

- You can't return from one of the branches
- You can't throw from one of the branches
- You can't use `?:` as a statement expression (that is, you can't write `condition ? "hello" : "world";` by itself
- You can't invoke a void method (directly) in one of the branches
- Perhaps most curiously, this:

  ```
  Number n;
  if (true) { n = Integer.valueOf(1); } else { n = Double.valueOf(1.0); }
  ```

  yields a different value to:

  ```
  Number n = true ? Integer.valueOf(1) : Double.valueOf(1.0);
  ```

  You may be surprised to learn that [`n instanceof Double` is `true`...](https://ideone.com/bz04aA)

Answer (score 0):

The quote below is incorrect:

> variable = (condition)? what happens if condition is false

It's the other way around:

> variable = (condition) ? valueiftrue : valueiffalse

Now, if you literally don't want anything to happen if condition is false, then you will need an `if`:

```
if (condition) {
    variable = valueiftrue;
}
```

if you are okay with allowing a dummy operation, then you can

```
variable = (condition) ? valueiftrue : variable;
```

So, we override variable with some value if the condition was true and we override it with itself otherwise.

Finally, if you enjoy debugging overcomplicated code (absolutely not recommended), then you can do something like this:

```
condition && ((variable = valueiftrue) == variable);
```

Answer (score -1):

" Ternary " means composed of three elements, it wouldn't be logical to use it if you have only one condition, keep it simple ! ;)